# Best way to create type of lists in C#

Tags: c#

What would be the best way to create a list?

```
List<string> Person = new List<string>() {"James", "Harry", "Jonson"};
```

or this one:

```
List<Person> Person = new List<Person>() {new Person("James"), new Person("Harry"), new Person("Jonson")};
```

```
class Person {
    
    public string Name;
    
    public Person(string newName) {
        this.Name = newName;
    }
}
```

Would it be better, or clearer to create types of lists that I use, or simply in this case to create a list of type string?

Comment: A class is only needed if you have more than one property.  You only have a name so the class is not needed.

Comment: For C# it is recommended you use strongly typed data structures.

Comment: @jdweng not always. If you are going to eventually extend, might as well do it as a class

Comment: It's also fairly standard with the "Value-Object" pattern.  It offers the safety of not being able to pass a `Person` instance into a method that takes a `Material` for example.  Once you have a  valid `Person` instance you can prevent passing in any random string that hasn't been validated.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, what is the point of `Person` if it only contains a single field of type `string`?

If you don't want to bother with having a type `Person` then a `List<string>` is sufficient, but if your data structure must contain more than just 1 field, then you should use a strongly typed list.

At a minimum, you need a type with a constructor

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string name, int age) 
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
    public string Name {get; }
    public int Age { get; }
}

static void Main()
{
    List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
    list.Add(new Person(...);
    list.Add(new Person(...);
}
```

Comment: The only one field argument is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple and start with strings.

```
var list = new List<string>() {"James", "Harry", "Jonson"};
```

If at some point you need "Person" objects, you can easily map the list onto a new list with the specific object type.

```
var persons = persons.Select( x => new Person(x) ).ToList();
```

Comment: What if in the future another programmer instead of "Person" add a "Car" to this list (wrongly)?

Comment: It's a list of strings. You can't add a Car to it, nor a Person for that matter. I think maybe you are asking "What if in the future another programmer adds the wrong string to this list?" The answer would depend on whether the list is ever validated and how exactly. But presumably they would have introduced a bug.